# Button to delete a file using php

Tags: php, loops, delete-file

I have a php loop which displays all of the files in a directory:

```
<?php

    // Define the full path to your folder from root
    $filepath =  'castlewp/cv/'; // The place the files will be uploaded to.
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $filepath;

    // Open the folder
    $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path");

    // Loop through the files
    while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {

    if($file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == "index.php" || $file == ".htaccess" || $file == ".htpasswd" )

        continue;
        echo "<li><a href=\"$file\">$file</a></li>";

    }
    // Close
    closedir($dir_handle);
?>
```

I am trying to find a way of adding a button next to each file which will delete the file. I have been playing around with php unlink but so far I have only been able to delete all of the files whenever a person accesses the script, this isn't what I want.

As far as I can tell this is a fairly simple thing to add but my knowledge of PHP is minor so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another script and pass the file name to it by GET parameters and in your current file add something like:

```
if($file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == "index.php" || $file == ".htaccess" || $file == ".htpasswd" )

    continue;
    echo "<li><a href=\"$file\">$file</a></li>";
    echo "<a href=\"delete.php?f={$file}\">Delete</a>";
```

Then in your delete.php file copy some of your existing code and modify it to delete the file:

```
$filepath =  'castlewp/cv/'; // The place the files will be uploaded to.
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $filepath;
if(empty($_GET['f']))
  exit();
$file = str_replace(array('/', '..'), '', $_GET['f']);
$filePath = realpath($path.$file);
if($filePath !== FALSE)
  unlink($filePath);
```

Consider this all as an example. You still have to add some security, but I think it is a start point.

Comment: Yes, consider some security!  `$_GET['f']=bla/../../bla.bla`

Comment: ^ Should send the filename in POST. Would have +1 for that.

Comment: @user1032531, I added replacing for ../, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

try, NOTE: you have to fix the url in the li tag to match your url

```
<?php
// Define the full path to your folder from root
$filepath =  'castlewp/cv/'; // The place the files will be uploaded to.
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $filepath;

// check if a file is send via GET variable
if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
$fullpath = $path.$file;
// check if file exists
if(file_exists($fullpath)) {
    unlink($fullpath);  
} else {
    // add some error handling here
} 
}

// Open the folder
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path");

// Loop through the files
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {

if($file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == "index.php" || $file == ".htaccess" || $file == ".htpasswd" )

    continue;
    echo "<li><a href=\"yoururl?file=$file\">$file</a></li>";

}
// Close
closedir($dir_handle);
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

First of all: format your code properly. I suggest you to use spacing and/or extra brackets to make your code more readable. The `continue` statement is the only one executed when the `if` condition is met, but your source formatting don't make think so.

You forgot also `<ul>` or `<ol>` tag for your list. Check W3C standards for lists.

A simple implementation is based on a  element with a submit button. This is plain html. Insert your

elements inside a form, each with a "delete" button. Specify a target for the form.

Generate this (or similar) html:

```
<form action="myfilemanager.php" method="post" name"=formfilemanager">
    <ul>
      <li>filename1.dat <input type="submit" name="filename1.dat" value="delete"/></li>
      <li>filename2.dat <input type="submit" name="filename2.dat" value="delete"/></li>
      ....
    </ul>
</form>
```

When you press on "delete" button for filename2.dat, you'll find some parameters on $_POST global:

```
filename2.dat=delete
```

If you cycle $_POST array like this

```
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) {
    if($v=='delete') { 
      // $k contains the file name to delete
      // SANITIZE you input, remove '..','%', whatever
      $k=str_replace(array('%','|','/','..'),'',$k);
      unlink($filepath.$k);
    }
}
```